# Flyway-gradle-plugin not functioning

Tags: flyway

I have been using flyway with maven very successfully (I love it!), but I can not seem to get even the demo working with gradle.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:3.0'
        classpath 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:1.1.7'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'flyway'
flyway {
    user = 'root'
    password = 'password'
    url = 'jdbc:mariadb://localhost/test'
}
```

src/main/resources/db/migration/V1__create_person_table.sql:

```
create table PERSON (PERSON_ID bigint auto_increment primary key,NAME varchar(100) not null);
```

gradle flywayMigrate -i

> Execution failed for task ':flywayMigrate'.
>
> > Error occurred while executing flywayMigrate   Unable to scan for SQL migrations in location: classpath:db/migration   Unable to
> >     determine URL for classpath location: db/migration (ClassLoader:
> >     java.net.URLClassLoader@42e85a1)

Setting flyway.locations explicitly didn't help, and there are no empty directories. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

This is the version info for gradle:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-09-08 10:40:39 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     e6cf70745ac11fa943e19294d19a2c527a669a53

Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_67 (Oracle Corporation 24.65-b04)
OS:           Linux 3.13.0-24-generic amd64
```

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to reproduce this. It's working for me, with both Gradle 1.9 and 2.1. Could you also post the debug log? And follow the steps of the get started page *exactly* to see if that works for you?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! The output with debug is here http://pastebin.com/A6LUhB4q

My setup is just:
mkdir -p src/main/resources/db/migration
vi src/main/resources/db/migration/V1__Create_person_table.sql
vi build.gradle
gradle flywayMigrate -i

Comment: Could you post a repro project somewhere? Thx

Comment: Ok I found the issue - apply plugin: 'java' was not in build.gradle. I feel silly, thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries. I am currently looking into changing the defaults, in order to make getting started with only sql migrations easier.